# Scala Array[Int]: BigO for max/min

Tags: algorithm, scala, big-o

for an Array of Int in scala 2.x, what is the BigO expression for Array[Int].max?
and then what is the expression for Array[Int].indexWhere(_ == max)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding time complexity, or BigO expression, both of them are O(n). Because it is an array, traverse all over the array to find the maximum or locate the position of a given number are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is really badly implemented, any `max` operator is going to be `O(n)`. You have to check every value once (so no less than `O(n)`), and if you check any value more than once you are not doing it right.